# Will a child process block the parent process in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

I'm sorry if this sound like a question I could just google, but I can't quite find the answer to it, or I couldn't understand the explanation.
My assumption is it would, or else how is it possible to pipe a child process' output to the parent process.
But here's what I don't understand:

```
let { spawn } = require('child_process');

if (process.argv[2] === "child") {
    console.log("In if!!");
}else{
    const child = spawn(process.execPath, [__filename, "child"]);
    child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        console.log("In else!! ", data.toString());
    });
}
```

Why is it outputting

> In else!! In if!!

I thought by spawning a child process, it execute it immediately, so it goes to the if statement, after consoling out `In if!!`, it resumes to the parent process, than reaches the event listener, thus consoling `In else!!`. Am I misunderstanding something?
My guess is that the `console.log`, doesn't actually logs, but return the `In if` String, then passes it to the parent process, which is the `data` in the callback. But if that's the case, why doesn't it actually logs?

Thank you for responding in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is a perfectly valid question.

Remember that even if you are spawning multiple processes (and each one will be then individually managed by the system), inside each NodeJS process code execution will remain sigle threaded.

The first thing about your code is that you are using the async version of the spawn command. Child Process is a NodeJS API so its execution will be governed by NodeJS rules (single thread), so it will run as any other async function in NodeJS (new "independent" process will not start working until spawn function executes).

With that being said, your parent process will add spawn to the pending work and it will run it when it finishes the current work (when your script ends).

If you want your parent process to wait for the child process, you will have to use spawnSync command.

See Asynchronous Process Creation and Synchronous Process Creation in the [NodeJS Child Process API Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) for more info.

Comment: But in the child process, why wouldn't it log `In if!!` in the first if statement? Is it because a child process's stdout is to pipe it to the parent process?  
Just to clear things out, could you explain what happens line by line? It would help me understand a lot faster.  
Thank you